# Extract specified number of words after a string in R

Tags: r, stringr, text-extraction

I am trying to extract the 4 words after the string "source:" in this example below.

```
library(stringr)

x <- data.frame(end = c("source: from animal origin as Vitamin A / all-trans-Retinol: Fish in general, liver and dairy products;", "source: Eggs, liver, certain fish species such as sardines, certain mushroom species such as shiitake", "source: Leafy green vegetables such as spinach; egg yolks; liver"))


x$source = str_extract(x$end, '[^source: ](.)*')
```

when I try the code above, I can extract all the text after "source:" into a new column. I was wondering if there is a way to extract only the first 4 words following "source", either using stringr or any other package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
trimws(stringr::str_extract(x$end, '(?<=source:\\s)(\\w+,?\\s){4}'))
#[1] "from animal origin as"       "Eggs, liver, certain fish"   
#    "Leafy green vegetables such"
```

`?<=` is positive lookbehind to search for `'source:'` followed by whitespace.

We capture 4 "words" after it including an optional comma and whitespace.

Comment: thank you, I did not know that trimws can be used for that purpose!